# How can I delete the bevel object once a curve is created?

Tags: modeling

I really like the curve feature. I think it has a lot of potential for creating curved objects for someone like myself who has a lot of difficulty creating a curve out of other meshes.

However, I really hate how curves pretty much need a bevel object, and that this bevel object CANNOT (to my knowledge) be deleted after the curved mesh is created.

Is there any way to create a curve, make a bend, have it be beveled, and not need a bevel object/be able to delete the bevel object afterwards?

Comment: Do you mean be***v***el?  Common practice is usually to put that sort of object on another layer which is not rendered.

Comment: In my opinion what you see as a limitation is a great way to keep things interactive and editable in a non destructive workflow. Just move the bevel object to a different layer and be happy. If you need to modify the main elements enable the layer that contains the bevel curves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the bevel objects needs to be kept around as long as you want the curve to be beveled. And it should be so as you can go back an change the bevel object curve as desired and it will update the bevel shape in your curve automatically.

If it gets in your way, you don't want it around, or you just feel its polluting your scene you can always hide it, move it to another layer or even place it it in a different scene in your blend file.

Alternatively if you are done modifying your curve and are absolutely sure you won't need to adjust it any further you can convert it to mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh from curve* as a final step.

You'll no longer need the bevel object but, this is discouraged and should only be used as a last resort, or if further modelling as mesh is needed, since it is a destructive procedure and you can't easily go back to non destructively editing both. Ideally do it to a duplicate of the object and keep a copy the original hidden.

Comment: How do I convert the curve to a mesh? That sounds like what I want to do.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is Alt+C > Mesh from curve option

Answer (score 5):

That will depend on the shape you want the bevel to be and whether you want to keep editing the curve. For odd shapes you will need to keep the bevel object as it defines the shape. You can hide the bevel object or move it to another layer to keep it out of the way. If you don't need to edit the tubing then you can setup your bevel and then convert it to a mesh with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and delete the curve objects.

For simple bevel shapes you don't need to use a bevel object. A square tube can be created by adding a bevel depth and leaving the resolution at 0.

[image: bevel settings]

By increasing the resolution to 1 or 2 you get a hexagonal or octagonal shaped tubing, higher values give a rounded cylindrical tube.

[image: hexagonal tube][image: octagonal tube]

If you want sharper edges you can add an edge split modifier.

[image: edge split]