# Changing section shape of a torus to produce a wheel rim in v2.72

Tags: objects

I am new to blender (v2.72).
I wish to create a multi-spoked  wheel as used on sportscars etc since 1900s.
The rim section is a stepped flattened v. 
In programs like solidworks and ansys I could draw a curve, extrude it around the axis of rotation, and then give it the necessary rim thickness.
In blender I looked at creating a torus and modifying the cross-sectionl shape, but I get lost in the interface.
Anybody been here before?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70394/why-curve-bevel-not-in-shape/70396#70396 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/planar-curve-with-width/57262 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/how-can-i-delete-the-bevel-object-once-a-curve-is-created/47380